# What is the domain of the estimates of the parameters in linear regression?

Tags: regression, variance, random-variable, regression-coefficients, linear

An answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/485031) stated the following:

> Here is another place where typical regression teaching sources are slippery. In some cases, they refer to the estimates $\hat \beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$ as functions of the (fixed) data that has been collected, and sometimes they refer to them as functions of the (random) potentially observable data, but use the same symbols $\hat \beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$ in either case.

If my understanding is correct, the estimates $\hat \beta_{0,n}$ and $\hat \beta_{1,n}$ are over the domain defined as follows:

$$ \Omega'_n = \{ \space \{(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \space \mid \space \omega \in I \space \}\space \space  \mid \space \space  I \in P(\Omega, n)\space \space \} $$

$\Omega$ here denotes the original universe, the one containing the individuals or the statistical units.

$P(\Omega, n)$ denotes the set of all sets that are a part of $\Omega$ and of cardinality $n$.

Often, the estimates are expressed as follows:

$$\hat{\beta_0} = \bar{Y_n} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X_n}$$

$$\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X_n})(Y_i-\bar{Y_n})}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X_n})^2}$$

In order for these formulas to be consistent with the quoted answer, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ need also to be interpreted as functions of the (random potentially observed data.

However, since the potentially observed data as defined in the domain $\Omega'_n$ don't contain any inherent ordering, it is perhabs difficult to define their image via each of the $X_i$ and $Y_i$. For this, it might be useful to re-define $\Omega'_n$ as the following:

$$ \Omega'_n = \bigcup_{I\in P(\Omega, n) \\} \space \bigcup_{\sigma \in S_n} \{(X(\omega_{\sigma{_i}}), Y(\omega_{\sigma{_i}}))_{i \in [|1, n|]}\} $$

$S_n$ is the symmetric group of degree $n$.

Now, for each $i \in \{1 \dots n\}$, $X_i$ can be defined as the function:

$$ \forall S \in P(\Omega,n) \space \space \forall \sigma \in S_n \space \space \space X_i(\space((X(\omega_{\sigma_{1}}),Y(\omega_{\sigma_{1}})), \dots, (X(\omega_{\sigma_{n}}), Y(\omega_{\sigma_{n}})) \space) =  X(\omega_{\sigma_{i}})$$

Similarly, for each for each $i \in \{1 \dots n\}$:

$$ \forall S \in P(\Omega,n) \space \space \forall \sigma \in S_n \space \space \space Y_i(\space((X(\omega_{\sigma_{1}}),Y(\omega_{\sigma_{1}})), \dots, (X(\omega_{\sigma_{n}}), Y(\omega_{\sigma_{n}})) \space) =  Y(\omega_{\sigma_{i}})$$

However, in most textbook explanations of linear regression, instead of using the formula $\hat{\beta_0} = \bar{Y_n} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X_n}$ for calculating the variances and the expectations of the estimates, they go instead with $\hat{\beta_0} = \bar{Y} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{x}$, which works with a fixed value of $X$. This poses further confusion, as it suggests that the estimates can have different variances and expectations depending on the used value of $X$. If these estimates are dependent on $x$, then why aren't the estimates written as $\hat \beta_{0, x}$ and $\hat \beta_{1, x}$ such that the x-dependency is clearly reflected? Another question would be when it might be useful to use one formula rather than the other, and in respect to which domain or universe?

I'm also confused as to whether $\bar{Y}$ refers to the random variable that is the function that associates each sequence of $(x_i,y_i)$ measurements of length $n$ to the mean of all the $y_i$ or only those such that $x_i = x$.

Comment: Isn't this just a reworking of your previous question?  If so, please just edit the previous one.  The answer you refer to, by the way, takes the position that regression is *always* about random variables $(X,Y)$ and concerns estimating the conditional distribution of $Y.$  The meaning of a bivariate random variable like $(X,Y)$ is clear--please review some of our posts about random variables.  Any estimates, like the $\hat\beta,$ are functions of these random variables and therefore are random variables too.  Perhaps, then, the key is to emphasize *conditional expectations.*

Comment: I'm not confused about the meaning of bivariate random variables. I'm also not asking about which variables the regression is about. What I don't understand, in particular, is what is the domain over which terms like $\hat \beta_1$ and $\hat \beta_0$ are defined. Clearly, they are not defined over $\Omega$, the domain of $X$ and $Y$, i.e. the one containing the individuals. So, which one is it?

Comment: Why do you mean "clearly not"?  When a quantity is a (measurable) function of a random variable, by composition it is a random variable.  So *clearly* the $\hat \beta$ are random variables defined on the same space as $(X,Y).$ Remember, though, "$(X,Y)$" represents the *entire sequence* of data: $X$ is the design matrix and $Y$ is the response vector.

Comment: What I mean is not that they are not random variables, but that they represent measures over not individuals or statistical units, as $X$ and $Y$ do, but over a series of $(X,Y)$ measures.  Instead of looking like this $X: \Omega -> IR$, they looks as follows: $\hat \beta: (\Omega ²)^n -> IR$. For the sake of simplicity, I'm only considering 2D linear regression here, and $X$ and $Y$ denote random variables with values in $IR$ insead of being vectors.

Comment: This is how *all* sampling works!  The same issue attaches to modeling, say, a coin flip.